# PySNMP hexValue to IP

Tags: python-3.x, pysnmp

I am using PySNMP to get the IPs of the CDP neighbors.
This is my current function, which works, but the output is of the type `hexValue`.

```
def get_neighbors():
    for (errorIndication,
         errorStatus,
         errorIndex,
         values) in nextCmd(SnmpEngine(),
                            CommunityData('public', mpModel=0),
                            UdpTransportTarget((SWITCH, 161)),
                            ContextData(),
                            ObjectType(ObjectIdentity('CISCO-CDP-MIB', 'cdpCacheAddress')).addAsn1MibSource('file://asn1/CISCO-CDP-MIB'),
                            lexicographicMode=False, lookupNames=True, lookupValues=True):
        print(values)
        for v in values:
            print(v)
```

It outputs the following:

```
[ObjectType(ObjectIdentity(ObjectName('1.3.6.1.4.1.9.9.23.1.2.1.1.4.10106.14')), CiscoNetworkAddress(hexValue='ac14103a'))]
CISCO-CDP-MIB::cdpCacheAddress.10106.14 = 0xac14103a
[ObjectType(ObjectIdentity(ObjectName('1.3.6.1.4.1.9.9.23.1.2.1.1.4.10125.9')), CiscoNetworkAddress(hexValue='ac1413fc'))]
CISCO-CDP-MIB::cdpCacheAddress.10125.9 = 0xac1413fc
```

How can I convert `0xac14103a` to an IP address?
Or is ist possible to somehow fetch the value of `CiscoNetworkAddress`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to `CISCO-TC` MIB, you have to interpret the address value by hand taking into account the type of the address as specified by `cacheAddressType` column:

```
CiscoNetworkAddress ::= TEXTUAL-CONVENTION
    DESCRIPTION
        "Represents a network layer address.  The length and format of
        the address is protocol dependent as follows:
        ip        4 octets
        ...
        ipv6      16 octets
        ...
        http     up to 70 octets
SYNTAX          OCTET STRING
```

If it is an IPv4 value, you can convert that octet-string into IPv4 address by hand:

```
# unpacking your `v` loop variable which is a tuple of SNMP var-bindings
# both `oid` and `value` are pysnmp objects representing SNMP types...
>>> oid, value = v
>>> '.'.join([str(x) for x in value.asNumbers()])
'172.20.16.58'
```

Or with `ipaddress` stdlib module:

```
>>> ipaddress.IPv4Address(value.asOctets())
IPv4Address('172.20.16.58')
```

Comment: But the IPv4 value is a hex value: `0xac1413fc`

Comment: That is true, though I'm not sure I understand your concern here. At any rate, I've edited my answer a little bit to make it closer to your code.

Comment: Thank you, this is exactly what I needed. I'm still new to SNMP in Python